# How to loop through an associative array and get the key?

Tags: php, loops, associative-array

My associative array:

```
$arr = array(
   1 => "Value1",
   2 => "Value2",
   10 => "Value10"
);
```

Using the following code, `$v` is filled with `$arr`'s values

```
 foreach ($arr as $v){
    echo $v;    // Value1, Value2, Value10
 }
```

How do I get `$arr`'s keys instead?

```
 foreach (.....){
    echo $k;    // 1, 2, 10
 }
```

Answer (score 400, accepted):

You can do:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
}
```

As described in [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 83):

If you use `array_keys()`, PHP will give you an array filled with just the keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 46):

Nobody answered with regular `for` loop? Sometimes I find it more readable and prefer `for` over `foreach`
So here it is:

```
$array = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'); 

$keys = array_keys($array);

for($i=0; $i < count($keys); ++$i) {
    echo $keys[$i] . ' ' . $array[$keys[$i]] . "\n";
}

/*
  prints:
  key1 value1
  key2 value2
*/
```

Comment: This is useful in some circumstances when foreach glitches out for unexplainable reasons. Good to always have at least two ways to do things.

Comment: There is no "unexplainable" reasons when it comes to computers.

Comment: Also useful for when you want to combine two subsequent array items together. i+=2 and then using $array[$keys[$i]]."_".$array[$keys[$i+1]]

Just incase someone else has this same problem

Comment: The bugs in foreach are described here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
If you are using PHP 7, nested foreaches and foreach references work as intended.
If you are using PHP 5, you should avoid using foreach by reference values and since all foreaches use internal array pointer ( current($Array) ) nesting foreaches or using PHP array functions can do weird things.

Comment: @jdrake  That would be so funny, if randomly foreach does not work and you just have to relace by a for-loop. This is something they should have implemented in INTERCAL

Answer (score 11):

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
```

Where $k is the key and $v is the value

Or if you just need the keys use array_keys()

Answer (score 8):

I use the following loop to get the key and value from an associative array

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<p>$key = $value</p>";
}
```

Comment: The only answer that describes clearly and concisely how to use both key and value in the loop!

Answer (score 5):

The following will allow you to get at both the key and value at the same time.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  echo($key);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While arguably being less clear this method is faster by roughly a factor of roughly 3.5 (At least on the box I used to test)

```
$foo = array(
    1 => "Value1",
    2 => "Value2",
    10 => "Value10"
);
while($bar = each($foo)){
    echo $bar[0] . " => " . $bar[1];
}
```

I would imagine that this is due to the fact the foreach copies the entire array before iterating over it.

Comment: please consider that 'each' was removed in the 8.0 PHP version.

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    echo($key);    // key
 }
```

Comment: Love that this was posted 4 seconds after codeaddict's answer, and 13 years later it's got a 0 score vs 381 score. Have a pity upvote lol

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found it in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    statement
}
```

> The current element's key will be assigned to the variable *$key* on each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$key => $val` to get the keys:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    1 => "Value1",
    2 => "Value2",
    10 => "Value10",
);

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
   print "$key\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$names = array("firstname"=>"maurice",
               "lastname"=>"muteti", 
               "contact"=>"7844433339");

foreach ($names as $name => $value) {
    echo $name." ".$value."</br>";
}

print_r($names);
?>
```