# PHP: Printing Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array

In PHP, I have an associative array like this

```
$a = array('who' => 'one', 'are' => 'two', 'you' => 'three');
```

How to write a `foreach` loop that goes through the array and access the array key and value so that I can manipulate them (in other words, I would be able to get `who` and `one` assigned to two variables `$key` and `$value`?

Comment: It is described in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - How to loop through a associative array and get the key name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951690/php-how-to-loop-through-a-associative-array-and-get-the-key-name)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: And how to format the output? Like I have $a['who'] = 10.99999, how to echo it out only as 10.99? (too demical digits)?

Comment: @TannerHoang: That is another question and already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+format+decimal

Comment: @Tanner: This feels like a completely other question. Have a look at `sprintf()` in the manual.

Comment: It is indeed another question. Anyway, you should use `printf("%.2f", $value);`

Comment: I actually used this one given Thiago `foreach` loop. `echo $key.": ".number_format($value,2)`;

Answer (score 8):

@Thiago already mentions the way to access the key and the corresponding value. This is of course the correct and preferred solution.

However, because you say

> so I can manipulate them

I want to suggest two other approaches

1. If you only want to manipulate the value, access it as reference

   ```
   foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
     $value = 'some new value';
   }
   ```
2. If you want to manipulate both the key and the value, you should going an other way

   ```
   foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
     $value = $array[$key];
     unset($array[$key]); // remove old key
     $array['new key'] = $value; // set value into new key
   }
   ```