# Using do-while loop in an associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm little confused as in how can I use do-while loop in an associative array in php. I don't have ordered indexes starting from 0 so I can't iterate simple as in case of C or Java

NOTE :: **I specifically want do-while sort of behavior...i.e. loop s'd execute atleast once in the beginning**

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Perhaps you should just be using `foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {}`

Comment: In PHP, `foreach` is typically used far more often than an indexed for loop (as in `for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)`)

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951690/php-how-to-loop-through-a-associative-array-and-get-the-key-name

Comment: No, I specifically want do-while sort of behavior...i.e. loop s'd execute atleast once

Comment: @user401445 Then it depends entirely on the kind of condition you want to evaluate. We need an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I can accomplish what I want using a separate function but seriously is there no iterator kind of behavior by which I can accomplish the same using any loop ?

Comment: @user401445 You're not getting me. You can't ask generically if a do-while can be used with an indexed array. Of course it can, it just depends on what you need to do. We need to see what problem, specifically, in code, you are trying to solve.  You can evaluate conditions against the return of `array_keys()` for example, or many other possiblities.

Comment: -1 for not posting the actual code you have trouble with.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel actual code is too complex to post

Comment: @Michael Yes..array_keys() is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user401445: I still dont get why you need such an "emulation" of a do-while if you could use `foreach`?

Comment: @scube I was having an array of results which I had to group in my loop based on some conditions...and was printing that when first member of next group of result was found. That printing condition was not getting executed for the last group of results... so do-while kinda behavior was something I wanted... didn't wanted to write any hacky code

Comment: you can always create a simplified test case. **especially** if you are investigating whatever new feature. make it work in a distinct simplified code, and then merge it into your main project.

Comment: without providing a real case nor real data you are limiting yourself to just one solution, which was posted by someone out of *guess*. if I were you, I wouldn't waste my time *such unproductive way*

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function.

```
$keys = array_keys($assocArray);
if(!empty($keys)) do{
  $key = array_pop($keys);
  // ...
}while(!empty($keys));
```

If you really want to use a do-while loop. But if a simple while loop is good for you, the first if isn't neccessary:

```
$keys = array_keys($assocArray);
while(!empty($keys)){
  $key = array_pop($keys);
  // ...
};
```

edit:

If you really want your loop to run at least once:

```
$keys = array_keys($assocArray);
do{
  $key = array_pop($keys);
  if($key===NULL){
    // first (and last) run for an empty array
  }else{
    // ...
  }
}while(!empty($keys));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to iterate the full array you should use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($array as $index => $value)
{
  // do some stuff
}
```

Of if you dont care about the index of your array:

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
  // do some stuff
}
```