# Getting status from paypal array

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

I am using the paypal-sdk. Everything is working great, but after a user pays, he is sent back to my site and paypal sends a lot of info back to me and the paypal-sdk adds it in an array. I just need to grab the 
"paypal" ["status"]=> string(8) "VERIFIED"
to make sure that the payment has been sent/done and the user's email that they paid with.

I use `var_dump($result);` to get these results.

That is the full array: https://pastebin.com/aRWcqkXH

I've tried

```
json_decode($result,true);
```

and

```
$status = $result->_propMap["payer"]->_propMap["status"];
```

but both results return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

@see paypal php sdk 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/source-class-PayPal.Api.Payer.html#60-68

maybe you can get by $result->getStatus()

Comment: i get a white / broken page with that

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951690/how-to-loop-through-an-associative-array-and-get-the-key) answer and modify it slightly to include a searchkey so as to produce this:

```
public static function displayRecursiveResults($arrayObject,$searchkey) {
    foreach($arrayObject as $key => $data) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            displayRecursiveResults($data,$searchkey);
        } elseif(is_object($data)) {
            displayRecursiveResults($data,$searchkey);
        } else {
            if ($key === $searchkey)
            echo "$key " . $data."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

You will be able to use it like this:

```
displayRecursiveResults($arr,'status');
```

Get the $arr value by using any api that extends the [PayPalModel's](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalModel.php) toArray() function (line 278) that will convert _propMap.

eg. my [Agreement Api](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Agreement.php) retrieves the payer info including the status field by using

```
 $payerinfo = $agreement->getPayer();
```

My $agreement value is obtained after the customer has approved the subscription and been redirected to my site and the redirect function run.

```
try {
                        $agreement = \PayPal\Api\Agreement::get($agreement->getId(), $apiContext);
                    } catch (Exception $ex) {
                        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_HTML;
                        \Yii::$app->response->data = $ex->getData();
                        exit(1);
                    }
```

I can then assign this to $arr by using:

```
$arr = $payerinfo->toArray();
```

From your data you are using the [Payment api](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php) which extends the PayPalResearchModel which inturn extends the PayPalModel so you will be able to use the toArray() function. Reduce the Payment array size by using the subarray Payer.

```
$payer = New Payer;
$my_payer = $payer->getStatus();
$arr = $my_payer->toArray();
```

And then assign this to the above function

```
displayRecursiveResults($arr,'status');
```

and the value returned should be 'verified'.