# How to get keys and values separately

Tags: php, arrays, json

(please don't say this is a duplicate, I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951690/how-to-loop-through-an-associative-array-and-get-the-key) first )
I have a json file like this

```
[{"studentName":"ali","studentPhone":"123"}, 

{"studentName":"veli","studentPhone":"134"}
```

need to get keys and values separately I am trying something like this

```
foreach ($jsonArray as $array ) {
    if(is_array($array)){

        while($bar = each($array)){
            echo $bar[1];
        }
```

but gives me this output :

```
ali123veli134hatca134dursun13444
```

I have also tried this way :

```
if(is_array($array)){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
```

Comment: What output are you trying to get?

Comment: what's the expected output ?

Comment: thanks for replying ....just names would be enough

Comment: `array_keys(json_decode($array, true))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a try like this way with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get only `studentName`

**Using normal foreach:**

```
<?php
$json = '[{"studentName":"ali","studentPhone":"123"}, {"studentName":"veli","studentPhone":"134"}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1); // the second params=1 makes json -> array
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $value['studentName']."<br/>";
    #echo $value['studentPhone']."<br/>";    
}
?>
```

**Using array_column():**

```
<?php
$json = '[{"studentName":"ali","studentPhone":"123"}, {"studentName":"veli","studentPhone":"134"}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1);
$names = array_column($array,'studentName');
print '<pre>';
print_r($names); // to get only studentName
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decode the json string, assign it to a variable, then loop through that variable and echo out the names (studenName).

*Ps: after decoding the `JSON` array we can acces the elements' names in each column using the `->` notation, as we have objects stored in that array.*

```php
// decoding the json string
$jsonArray = 
json_decode('[{"studentName":"ali","studentPhone":"123"}, 

{"studentName":"veli","studentPhone":"134"}]');
//loop through the array and print out the studentName
foreach($jsonArray as $obj) {
  echo $obj->studentName . ' ';
  // if you want to print the students phones, uncomment the next line.
  //echo $obj->studentPhone . ' ';
}
// output: ali veli
```