# Associative array loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I had this i array and i try to loop trough.

```
Output of:<?php print_r($this);?>

[text] => a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"de";s:5:"label";s:70:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"en";s:5:"label";s:70:"<img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}}
```

I tried:

```
<?php $str ='de'; ?>

    <?php foreach ($this->text as $key => $item):?>
        <?php if ($key == $str):?>
            <span class="firstelement hide-on-mobile"><?php echo $item; ?></span>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

I got no output.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include your question  What happens when you try it? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through an associative array and get the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951690/how-to-loop-through-an-associative-array-and-get-the-key)

Comment: @LuckyStarr `$this->text` is not an associative array, he just thinks it is. It is a multidimensional array instead

Comment: @LuckyStarr And the question you flagged as duplicate has nothing to do with what he wants either, even if it was an associative array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your array seems to be serialized. To access it with code, you would need to `unserialize()` it first. (In case you did not do this already)

```
$labels = unserialize($this->text);
```

The problem you have then is, that you misinterpreted the structure of your array. Your array is built like this:

```
$labels = [
    0 => [
        'value' => 'de',
        'label' => '<img ... />'
    ],
    1 => [
        'value' => 'en',
        'label' => '<img ... />'
    ]
]
```

As you can see, it is an array that contains arrays itself. (multidimensional array) When the array gets iterated in your `for` loop, `$key` gets assigned the **outer** keys, so `0` and `1`. What you want instead, is to access the inner keys. This can only be done by accessing them directly:

```
for($labels as $value) {
    if ($value['value'] === $str) {
        ?>
        <span class="firstelement hide-on-mobile"><?= $value['label'] ?></span>
        <?php
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop neither accesses the outer keys anymore, because they are not relevant, as well as accessing the inner array's fields with `$value['value']` and `$value['label']` directly.

Comment: Hi, except that the serialisation appears to have been incorrectly done when the data was serialised. See my answer for an explanation

Comment: Thats Odd, I get errors when trying to unserialize. Never mind I had a great time playing with it :)

Comment: I dont got any error :)  $this->text is something i got for a cms i use.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$this->text` is the result of a `serialize()` run on an PHP array presumably to store it on a table column. It must therefore be `unserialized()` back to a PHP array before you can make any use of it as a PHP array.

However, when I tried that there also appears to be errors in the original serialisation so as it is `$this->text` is corrupt and unusable as it stands.

Having copied your serialized string from your question, when trying to unserialise it I get this error

```
$x = 'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"de";s:5:"label";s:70:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"en";s:5:"label";s:70:"<img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}}';
$y = unserialize($x);
print_r($y);
```

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 123 of 256 bytes in D:\PHP-SOURCE\tst.php on line 4

This is because this part of the string,

```
s:70:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">"
```

does not correctly count the following string, as there are 74 characters in the string

```
"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">"
```

If we fix that by correcting the count to `74` like this

```
s:74:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">"
```

And rerunning the unserialise

```
$x = 'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"de";s:5:"label";s:74:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"en";s:5:"label";s:70:"<img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}}';
$y = unserialize($x);
print_r($y);
```

There is another similiar error in the string counts

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 248 of 256 bytes in D:\PHP-SOURCE\tst.php on line 8

```
s:70:"<img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">"
```

So if we also fix that error by making the count `74` and rerun

```
$x = 'a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"de";s:5:"label";s:74:"<img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";s:2:"en";s:5:"label";s:74:"<img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">";}}';
$y = unserialize($x);
print_r($y);
```

We get a correctly unserialised array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => de
            [label] => <img src="assets/images/e/de-02d3d6ee.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => en
            [label] => <img src="assets/images/7/en-c5c09767.jpg"  width="40" height="28" alt="">
        )

)
```

> So in short, if you got this data from a database You will need to look at the code that is serialising this data before it is placed on the database to work out why it is **Incorectly** serialising the array in the first place.