How to get Datetime's object's property such has timezone
How can I echo this PHP array with objects in an foreach loop?
I want to echo each value in different parts of my code.
array(2) {
  ["new_years_day"]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  ["juneteenth"]=>
  object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2024-06-19 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
}

I tried this code but it this doesn't do the job ($holidaysThisYear is the name of the array):
<?php foreach($holidaysThisYear as $holidayThisYear) {
  echo $holidayThisYear->timezone;
} ?>


https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.gettimezone.php

For future reference, "doesn't do the job" isn't a useful problem description. Tell us exactly what output you get - whether that's an empty space, an error message/warning, some other unexpected result, or whatever. Don't assume we're going to guess or want to sit working it out - tell us what you know, and then it's much easier and quicker to help you!! See also [ask].

Thanks for your help! Is there also a way to echo the array entry titles "new_years_day" and "juneteenth"?

Yep - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951708/5947043 (and many others)

The only question, how this timezone stuff is related to foreach (and objects)

As per its documentation, the DateTime class doesn't have any public properties.
You need to use the documented getTimezone() function instead, if you want to retrieve the timezone.
Since the timezone it returns is itself an object and also has no public properties, you then need to use the getName() function from that class to get the timezone's readable name.
For example:
echo $holidayThisYear->getTimezone()->getName();

As you can see, this is all clearly laid out in the PHP documentation already.
Live demo: https://3v4l.org/hhqJU

When you works with you must to use the relevant class methods. In your case getTimezone() and getName()
<?php
$holidaysThisYear = [
    "new_years_day" => new DateTime("2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000"),
    "juneteenth" => new DateTime("2024-06-19 00:00:00.000000")
];


foreach($holidaysThisYear as $holidayThisYear) {
    echo $holidayThisYear->getTimezone()->getName();
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

Play with PHP online

You are very close in your question.
The issue you are trying is to access the timezone property directly, but it's nested inside the DateTime object. You need to access the date property first, and then the timezone property.
Here is example
<?php foreach ($holidaysThisYear as $holidayThisYear) {
  echo $holidayThisYear->date->timezone;
} ?>

if you like to access other properties, like data string, you can do this.
<?php foreach ($holidaysThisYear as $holidayThisYear) {
  echo $holidayThisYear->date->format('Y-m-d'); // outputs the date string
  echo $holidayThisYear->timezone; // outputs the timezone string
} ?>

Note, I am using format() method to format the date string to Y-m-d format. You can adjust the format as you need.
